# When I run pod install, using cocoapods gem, I get a LoadError

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby

I've installed the ruby 2.1.1 and rails 4 via RVM. I'm able to install cocoapods gem just fine, but if I put in pods in my pods file to be installed and then run 'pod install', I get the following error

````
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 0.29.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
    RubyGems : 2.2.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
       Xcode : 5.0.2 (5A3005)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 358968cdff6fe6a41e7861b805f6f4ac573c9fad
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
```

### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_SHA1_Finish
  Referenced from: /Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/digest/sha1.bundle - /Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/digest/sha1.bundle
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:149:in `cache_path'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:195:in `cache_exist?'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:31:in `download!'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:101:in `block in download'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:25:in `block in ui_action'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:24:in `ui_action'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-downloader-0.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:99:in `download'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:101:in `download_source'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:64:in `install!'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:263:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:73:in `titled_section'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:236:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `each'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `install_pod_sources'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:103:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:101:in `download_dependencies'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:87:in `install!'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:38:in `run_install_with_update'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:68:in `run'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:213:in `run'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
````

```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put the version for the SVProgressHUD, something like this:

`pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.0'`